# trouble moving socketio server from localhost to ssl nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, socket.io, ubuntu-16.04

Some of the stesp I have taken include

- modifying nginx setup

  ```
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

    server {
      server_name services.parleyvale.com;
    ...
    location /s2gio/ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3222;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }...
  ```

but network tab gave me 404's so on my client (react) app added

- modifying client

  ```
    //var socket = io.connect(cfg.urls.socket)

    var socket = io.connect(cfg.urls.socket,{
      secure: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      path: '/s2gio/socket.io'
    });
  ```

slightly better but the server was not responding so on the server added

- modifying server

  ```
    //const io = require('socket.io')(server)

    const io = require('socket.io')(server,
    { 
      secure: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false, 
      path: '/s2gio/socket.io'
    });

    io.of('/s2gio')
  ```

now the messages from client show up on server but they do not 'emit' from the server.

comparing the ssl nginx debug file

```
  2020-03-12T19:12:36.309Z socket.io:socket emitting event ["message",{"lid":"Jutebi","product":"Avacado","done":1,"jsod":"","loc":"produce"}]
  2020-03-12T19:12:36.309Z socket.io:socket dispatching an event ["message",{"lid":"Jutebi","product":"Avacado","done":1,"jsod":"","loc":"produce"}]
```

that's all I get before they both go back to writing 2's and 3's. But localhost does `encodes, encoding, writing and sending`

```
  2020-03-12T19:12:36.309Z socket.io:socket emitting event ["message",{"lid":"Jutebi","product":"Avacado","done":1,"jsod":"","loc":"produce"}]
  2020-03-12T19:12:36.309Z socket.io:socket dispatching an event ["message",{"lid":"Jutebi","product":"Avacado","done":1,"jsod":"","loc":"produce"}]
  message:  { lid: 'Jutebi',
    product: 'Red potatoes',
    done: 0,
    jsod: '',
    loc: 'dairy' }
    socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":2,"data":["message",{"lid":"Jutebi","product":"Red potatoes","done":0,"jsod":"","loc":"dairy"}],"nsp":"/"} +16ms
    socket.io-parser encoded {"type":2,"data":["message",{"lid":"Jutebi","product":"Red potatoes","done":0,"jsod":"","loc":"dairy"}],"nsp":"/"} as 2["message",{"lid":"Jutebi","product":"Red potatoes","done":0,"jsod":"","loc":"dairy"}] +0ms
    socket.io:client writing packet ["2[\"message\",{\"lid\":\"Jutebi\",\"product\":\"Red potatoes\",\"done\":0,\"jsod\":\"\",\"loc\":\"dairy\"}]"] +15m
    engine:socket sending packet "message" (2["message",{"lid":"Jutebi","product":"Red potatoes","done":0,"jsod":"","loc":"dairy"}]) +17ms
    engine:ws writing "42["message",{"lid":"Jutebi","product":"Red potatoes","done":0,"jsod":"","loc":"dairy"}]" +19ms
    qry.sql:  INSERT INTO items SET `lid` = 'Jutebi', `product` = 'Red potatoes', `done` = 0, `jsod` = '', `loc` = 'dairy' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `lid` = 'Jutebi', `product` = 'Red potatoes', `done` = 0, `jsod` = '', `loc` = 'dairy'
```

the server is pretty simple

```
  const io = require('socket.io')(server);

  io.on('connect', (socket) => {
    io.emit('message', 'connected io')


    socket.on('switch2room', (room)=>{
      console.log('swwwwww')
      console.log('switch2room: ', room)
      socket.leaveAll()
      socket.join(room, ()=>{
        console.log('subscribe ', socket.rooms);  
        io.in(room).emit('message', `inside ${room} party people?`)   
      })
    })

    socket.on('message', (message)=>{
      console.log('message: ', message)
      io.in('/s2gio/'+message.lid).emit('message',message)
      if(message.done==-1){
        const qry=conn.query('DELETE FROM items WHERE lid=? AND product=?',[message.lid,message.product],()=>{
          console.log('qry.sql: ', qry.sql)
        })
      }else{
        const qry = conn.query('INSERT INTO items SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?', [message,message], (error,results)=>{
          console.log('qry.sql: ', qry.sql)
        })
      }
    })
  });

  server.listen(cfg.port.socket);
  console.log('wss listening on '+cfg.port.socket);
```

I also tried adding 'namespace' in emit on the server

```
  io.on('connect', (socket) => {
    io.emit('message', '/s2gio/connected io')
  ...
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: localhost is running  ubuntu 16.04 and  nginx 1.10.3. The server is running the same. Socket.io is version 2.3.0

Comment: It could be a lot of things, please check that all services are running and listening on the correct ports, and provide nginx logs

Comment: It could be that you are missing a path suffix for the: "proxy_pass" setting, but it is hard to know if there is no access log for your socket.io server, or a tcpdump/wireshark analysis or nginx debug logging showing the exact behavior and compare it to the intended behavior by your application. See this site for some practical examples of what you could do: https://www.liaohuqiu.net/posts/nginx-proxy-pass/